# Use .JSON for Backbone Model URL

Tags: url, backbone.js, file-extension

I would like to change the url to end with **.json** in Backbone. Here's my issue:

I want to use the same URI for the HTML version of my site and the JSON API (used by the HTML version). So both my URIs should look like

GET **website.com/users/1** to get info about the user with id 1 in HTML. The HTML page fetches **website.com/users/1.json**.

Howewer, backbone doesn't let me change the extension of the url of my models:

```
var User = Backbone.Model.extend({
  url:'users.json'
});
```

does'nt work

I understand that Backbone doesn't integrate the idea of extension in its URL, so what possibilitys do I have ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override url function, and in that function you can generate url you want :

```
url: function(){
   return 'users/'+this.id+'.json'
}
```

[backbone documentaion](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-urlRoot)